# Java syntax highlighting for [jaxb] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

When the [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb) tag is present on a question, I think it is generally safe to apply Java syntax highlighting. Example question:

[JAXB HashMap unmappable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820092/jaxb-hashmap-unmappable/8770027)

Alternatively, XML syntax highlighting could be applied, but usually the interesting part of the question is about how to use JAXB in Java

Comment: Is there any reason to not just add the `java` tag?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: `java` is redundant with the `j` in `jaxb`. Some may argue that the `java` tag is thus not necessary. But then again, this rule would apply to many other tags, too. Maybe that goes too far?